# Unable to set up Anaconda on Windows : Path problems

Tags: python, cygwin, windows-8.1, anaconda

I've been trying to setup Anaconda 1.8 on Windows 8.1 but cant get Windows to detect it for the life of me. I've tried adding it in the system path by editing the environment variables and adding `C:\Anaconda`.

I've tried the Cygwin route and tried to edit `.bashrc`  and `.profile`, but the path doesn't seem to reflect the presence of Anaconda.

Powershell output

```
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Were you expecting another result? It seems to me that Anaconda is just a package of libraries. If you type 'python' in Powershell, all it does is start the python interpreter, so the result seems normal.

Comment: But when I try to import `IPython` or `numpy` it throws an `ImportError`. Plus this https://github.com/cs109/content/wiki/Installing-Python tells me that I should get some info about Anaconda like `Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.6.1 (x86_64)|` when I start Python. This isnt happening

Comment: Try to type conda in the command line. It's a program that should be bundled with anaconda. You probably just need to remove an old python installation from path.

Comment: Typing `conda` returns a list of optional arguements. How do I replace the existing python installation with conda ?

Comment: Good, that means anaconda is actually installed. You need to remove the path to the old python installation from the system environment variable PATH. And probably have to add anaconda there if it's not there already.

Comment: Can I remove both `Python27` and `Python27\Scripts` from the Path? `Python27` was the earlier installation

Comment: NB!  The "activate" command from the anaconda distribution does not work properly at time of writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look closely at your PATH.  If you installed Python before, maybe from the official Python.org installer, it may appear in your PATH before the C:\Anaconda\bin directory.  If so, then this is your problem, and you should remove that other Python installation if you haven't customized it in any way.  If you have customized it, i.e. you have installed packages into it and you don't want to remove it, then you need to move it to the end of your PATH, after the C:\Anaconda\bin entry.

For a nice, graphical editor for your PATH, check out Path Editor: http://patheditor2.codeplex.com/

Comment: Also, [rapid environment editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about) is really good.

Comment: Hi Peter. My System PATH has three different URLs - are they all required? 
`C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin`