# Why can I not always import pandas

Tags: python, windows, pandas, ipython

I've done the following:

```
conda install pandas
```

If I open iPython notebook and import like this everything is happy:

```
import pandas
```

If I open cmd and type `python` I get the following:

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

Then if I try the same import the following happens:

```
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
```

What is happening and how do I get around this?

---

**note**

If I look at my current PATH variable I see this:

[image]

When I run `conda info --envs` in `cmd` it returns the following:

```
# conda environments:
#
root                  *  C:\Users\jasonq\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3
```

Can I change my PATH so only `conda` python is used?

Comment: Clearly you have multiple python instances in your OS, in one of them (Anaconda) pandas is installed, in other is not. Try `python -m pip install pandas`.

Comment: what happens when you use `conda info --envs` in cmd?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it returns this `root                  *  C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Start ipython and find the path of the executable that it is using:

```
$ ipython
In [1]: import sys
In [2]: print(sys.executable)
/home/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

Step 2: Do the same with your python

```
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/home/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Your problem is that the two executables will not be the same. I have not used windows in too long, so you'll have to google ([maybe this one](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469160-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-)) and find out how to make sure they are both the same.

Comment: both the above return the same path to `python.exe`. So python scripts that I'm running are hitting what looks like my only `python.exe` but when I do `import pandas` it fails ... maybe I can just change `import pandas` to be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

You have several instances of Python on your host machine.  The one you launch with Anaconda has `pandas` installed but the default python does not.

You need to install `pandas` on your default version of python.  You can do this in Windows with the following command:

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

I'm assuming you're using Windows since you mentioned `cmd`.

Comment: I would  argue against the above course of action, especially on Windows. Instead, rather, modify your environment to use the Anaconda instance when you use the command "python" - installing the scipy stack on Windows is fraught with dangers and you can end up with a suboptimal installation. These are the reasons that distributions like Anaconda exist.

Comment: You should post that as an answer, as that is a very very ideal solution.  I was also thinking it'd be more appropriate to change the environment variables, but I don't know enough about Windows to post that as an answer

Comment: Unfortunately I am in the same boat when it comes to Windows!

Comment: I don't believe this is not a good idea. Why is is necessary to install the same software twice on the same machine?

Comment: @whytheq the question remains unanswered, so if you have a better answer perhaps you should post it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is this a trivial thing to do "modify your environment to use the Anaconda instance when you use the command "python" " ? Just change my PATH env variable and it is done?

Comment: @whytheq yes, it is pretty trivial. Try looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946025/unable-to-set-up-anaconda-on-windows-path-problems

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answers let to the solution. This was my original `PATH env variable`:

[image]

Even though Anaconda features in the above, and it is higher up the order, my system still seemed to insist on using the `\Programs\Python35-32` version of the `python.exe` file.

Amending `PATH` to the following by just deleting the `\Programs\Python35-32` elements:

[image]

Now I get the following results:

```
PS > ipython
In [1]: import sys
In [2]: print(sys.executable)
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe

PS > python
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:49:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe
```