# Conda will not run

Tags: python, conda

I've tried to launch an ipython notebook, but it seems conda won't run.

When I run `jupyter notebook` I get an error saying `cannot open C:\Users\...\Scripts\conda-script.py`.

Even running `conda - conda uninstall` raises the same error.  Any thoughts on fixes?

Running on windows.

Comment: Have you checked the folder privileges?

Comment: Can you run jupyter --version

Comment: @MichaelMMeskhi yes.  Returns 4.1.0

Comment: The only problem that comes to mind is that it cannot access other user folder to run. The documentation says: http://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/what_is_jupyter.html#notebook-app

Comment: Try running `ipython notebook` if that works then the firewall is blocking the connection

Comment: `ipyton notebook` does not work either.

Comment: Can you find anaconda in your start menu? If so try running it from there.

Comment: Whats the exact PATH for conda?

Comment: Conda wont run from the start menu either.  How can I find the Anaconda path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20964134/5110035